# Derivative of an iterative vector function?

Tags: derivatives, matrix-equations, iterated-function-system

I am trying to solve the following problem

I have some vector-matrix product of the form $\textbf{y} = \textbf{w} \cdot \textbf{X}(\textbf{x})$. Here, $\textbf{x}=[x_1, x_2, ... , x_N]$ and the matrix $ \textbf{X}(\textbf{x}) $ takes the form:
$$
\textbf{X}(\textbf{x}) = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & ... & 1 \\
x_1 & x_2 & ... & x_N \\
u^{(1)}_1 & u^{(2)}_1 & ... & u^{(N)}_1 \\
\vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\
u^{(1)}_n & u^{(2)}_n & ... & u^{(N)}_n
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & ... & 1 \\
x_1 & x_2 & ... & x_N \\
\textbf{u}^{(1)} & \textbf{u}^{(2)} & ... & \textbf{u}^{(N)} 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The vectors $\textbf{u}$ are found iteratively: $$\textbf{u}^{(i)} = f(x_{i-1},\textbf{u}^{(i-1)})$$
with $\textbf{u}^{(1)} = \textbf{0}$. The row-vector $\textbf{w}$ is a vector of constants and does not depend on $\textbf{x}$. I am wanting to find $$\frac{d\textbf{y}}{d\textbf{x}} = \frac{d}{d\textbf{x}} \left( \textbf{w} \cdot \textbf{X}(\textbf{x}) \right)$$
but am troubled on how one should handle the vectors $\textbf{u}$ since they are iterative. Any help would be greatly appreciated. If I am not making sense and should clarify anything please do let me know haha.

Thanks!

Comment: Is $n=N$ ? Also, your definition of $\mathbf{u}^{(1)}=0$ is unclear to me since this implies that all the entries under $x_1$ in the first column of $\mathbf{X(x)}$ is equal to zero.

Comment: Also, sharing the context of the problem and some of your attempts to solve it would be valuable to anyone who would want to answer your question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Let me clarify, here $n$ and $N$ are different (bad choice of notation). Yes you are correct, all entries under $x_1$ are zero. 
I am not too sure if you are familiar with Echo State neural networks (ESN), but i am trying to differentiate the ESN output with respect to the input.

Comment: Is it clear that $$\dfrac{d\mathbf{y}}{d\mathbf{x}}= \dfrac{d\mathbf{w}}{d\mathbf{x}}\cdot\mathbf{X} + \mathbf{w}\cdot\dfrac{d\mathbf{X}}{d\mathbf{x}} =\mathbf{0}+\mathbf{w}\cdot\dfrac{d\mathbf{X}}{d\mathbf{x}} ?$$ Do you know how to take a matrix derivative?

Comment: I do, I am just maybe confused since the vectors $\textbf{u}$ are iterative how would I take those derivatives within $\textbf{X}$?

Comment: It would be better if you accept an answer if it has answered your question properly. Otherwise, this question is still active.

Comment: Sorry! Still new to this. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have defined,
$$\mathbf{X(x)} = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & ... & 1 \\
x_1 & x_2 & ... & x_N \\
\textbf{u}^{(1)} & \textbf{u}^{(2)} & ... & \textbf{u}^{(N)} 
\end{bmatrix}.$$
We note that $$\frac{d\mathbf y}{d\mathbf x} = \mathbf{w}\cdot \frac{d\mathbf {X(x)}}{d\mathbf x}.$$
Now, by definition, $$\frac{d\mathbf {X(x)}}{d\mathbf x} = \begin{bmatrix}
\dfrac{d}{d\mathbf x}(1) & \dfrac{d}{d\mathbf x}(1) & \cdots & \dfrac{d}{d\mathbf x}(1) \\ \\
\dfrac{d}{d\mathbf x}(x_1) & \dfrac{d}{d\mathbf x}(x_2) & \cdots & \dfrac{d}{d\mathbf x}(x_n) \\ \\
\dfrac{d}{d\mathbf x}(\textbf{u}^{(1)}) & \dfrac{d}{d\mathbf x}(\textbf{u}^{(2)}) & \cdots & \dfrac{d}{d\mathbf x}(\textbf{u}^{(N)}) 
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ \\
\dfrac{d}{d\mathbf x}(x_1) & \dfrac{d}{d\mathbf x}(x_2) & \cdots & \dfrac{d}{d\mathbf x}(x_n) \\ \\
\dfrac{d}{d\mathbf x}(\textbf{u}^{(1)}) & \dfrac{d}{d\mathbf x}(\textbf{u}^{(2)}) & \cdots & \dfrac{d}{d\mathbf x}(\textbf{u}^{(N)}) 
\end{bmatrix},$$
where in the second row, $\dfrac{d}{d\mathbf x}(x_i) = \mathbf{e}_i$ and in the last row, $\dfrac{d}{d\mathbf x}(\textbf{u}^{(i)}) = \textbf{u}^{(i+1)}$,
where $\textbf{u}^{(i+1)}$ is in fact the Jacobian Matrix (or the pushforward operator) and can be expressed in matrix form as follows:
$$\dfrac{d}{d\mathbf x}(\textbf{u}^{(i)}) = \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{\partial u^{(i)}_1}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial u^{(i)}_1}{\partial x_2} & \cdots & \frac{\partial u^{(i)}_1}{\partial x_N}\\
    \frac{\partial u^{(i)}_2}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial u^{(i)}_2}{\partial x_2} & \cdots & \frac{\partial u^{(i)}_2}{\partial x_N}\\
    \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
    \frac{\partial u^{(i)}_n}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial u^{(i)}_n}{\partial x_2} & \cdots & \frac{\partial u^{(i)}_n}{\partial x_N}\\
  \end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: thank you so much! Can you explain to be briefly why $\frac{d}{d \textbf{x}} (\textbf{u}^{(i)}) = \textbf{u}^{(i+1)}$ ?

Comment: My bad. I forgot that in this context $\mathbf {u}^{(i+1)}$ has a different meaning. I meant it to be a shorthand for the Jacobian matrix obtained. I have now included it in my answer. Hope this answers your questions.

Comment: Okay, so to confirm in this context $\frac{d}{dx} \textbf{u}^{(i)}$ is not equal to $\textbf{u}^{(i+1)}$ correct? Rather it is equal to the Jacobian

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I have made a final edit to fully clarify this notation.

Comment: Okay great! I will give some more context here. The vector $\textbf{x}$ is a vector grid points (say discrete spatial points).  In your third equation with $\frac{ d \textbf{X} (\textbf{x}) } { d \textbf{x} } $, can I take a vector-to-vector derivative of each row with respect to $\textbf{x}$ (say via finite difference) since they are the same size?

Comment: @APMATH24 yes, you can. That is in fact the definition of a matrix derivative w.r.t. to a vector.